# Multiple value parameter only showing first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008

I have an SQL Server stored procedure that I'm trying to make an SSRS report from. The sp has a parameter in it. The parameter works in SSRS when calling a single value. However, when calling both values, only the first one is returned. 
Here's something important- The 'Active' field is a bit data type, so this is where the problem most likely lies.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_RptRC]

@Active VARCHAR(1)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT [Funding]
      ,[4thChar]
      ,REPLACE([Description], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') [Description]
      ,[Comments]
      ,CAST(Active AS VARCHAR(1)) Active
      ,[IsDeleted]
      ,[LastModifiedBy]
      ,[LastModifiedDate]
  FROM [RC]

  WHERE Active IN (@Active)

  END
```

Comment: Are you calling the proc like `EXEC [dbo].[USP_RptRC] '0,1'`?

Comment: In the dataset properties, I'm using query type stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

First your parameter is only a length of 1.  Second, since you are using 'Where In' you will need to do a little extra work.  I had the same issue in the past and this article helped me get it working.

https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/passing-multi-value-parameter-in-stored-procedure-ssrs-report/

Answer (score 0):

Since @Active is a `VARCHAR(1)`, which could be a `CHAR` or `INT` if you are always using 1 or 0, you can only pass in one of the values. If you want the ability to return where `Active` is 1 or 0, then do this:

```
    @Active VARCHAR(1) = NULL
    AS
BEGIN
SELECT [Funding]
      ,[4thChar]
      ,REPLACE([Description], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') [Description]
      ,[Comments]
      ,CAST(Active AS VARCHAR(1)) Active
      ,[IsDeleted]
      ,[LastModifiedBy]
      ,[LastModifiedDate]
  FROM [RC]

    WHERE @Active IS NULL or Active = @Active
```

Then in your SSRS report, just set the default value of your parameter to NULL, and/or in the Parameter settings, allow NULL values along with your explicit choices of 1 and 0. When NULL is selected, both 1 and 0 will be returned. Of course you can label the parameter choice in SSRS to "All" or "Inactive & Active" and pass NULL as the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL wise - '0,1' is not two values, it's one and in the context you use it it's one string value. But since your parameter length is limited (by you) to 1, the engine trims everything after the first character to convert '0,1' into '0'. If you pass '1,whatever' you'll get '1' in you stored procedure. That's way "only the first one is returned".

But since the `@Active` is `bit` you should declare it as `bit`. Then change your logic to include appropriate subset of records when you receive `NULL` for `@Active`, like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_RptRC]
@Active VARCHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [Funding]
          ,[4thChar]
          ,REPLACE([Description], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') [Description]
          ,[Comments]
          ,CAST(Active AS VARCHAR(1)) Active
          ,[IsDeleted]
          ,[LastModifiedBy]
          ,[LastModifiedDate]
    FROM [RC]
    WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @Active IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE
        CASE WHEN Active = @Active THEN 1 ELSE -1
END
```